# Apache POI - manipulating .doc lose images

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, doc

Good morning everyone!
The intention was to do a simple text replace on a .doc file that was provided to me.
I had already tried this procedure on plain .docx and it worked, but on this .doc it isn't working.

```
HWPFDocument docCandidato = null;

try {
    String filePath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/templates/cv_template.doc").getPath();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream);
    docCandidato = new HWPFDocument(fileSystem);        
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("--------> ERROR: ", e);
}
        
docCandidato = replaceText(docCandidato, "xxx", candidato.getNome().concat(" ").concat(candidato.getCognome()));

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    docCandidato.write(out);
    out.close();
    docCandidato.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("--------> ERROR: ", e);
}
```

```
private HWPFDocument replaceText(HWPFDocument doc, String originalText, String updatedText) {
    Range range = doc.getRange();
    range.replaceText(originalText, updatedText);
    return doc;
}
```

Beyond this, the most serious problem is that when I go to save the file flow without having manipulated anything, the images inside the document are lost.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

[image]

Has anyone ever had this problem?
How he solved it?

Thanks!

Save the template of a doc file without losing information.

Comment: The specific case is with the .doc.... but converting it into a .docx works, i.e. there is no loss of images.

Comment: Switch to `.docx` - the `.doc` format is pretty horrible and there haven't been enough contributions to Apache POI for complete coverage of it

Comment: @Gagravarr you're not entirely wrong... I first tried to convert the file from .doc to .docx and by carrying out the same procedure, the ones already present in the document are not lost...